# how to break children loops only

Tags: php

I won't break a loop that is in another loop 
these are my codes

```
                for ($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++) {
//                some codes
                for ($i1 = 0; $i1 < 10; $i1++) {
                    if (a condition)
                    {
//                        i want break this loop not parent loop
                    }
                }
                //                some codes

            }
```

if I use `break;`  parent loop will break too but I won't `break` only work for child loop
thanks for your answers

Comment: `break` will only exit one level, if the outer loop is exiting then there is something else which we can't see going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this and its worked

```
             for ($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++) {
//                some codes
                for ($i1 = 0; $i1 < 10; $i1++) {
                    if (a condition)
                    {
                          $i1=11;
                    }
                }
                //                some codes

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

`break` only breaks out of the loop it's called in. If you want to break out of an outer control structure, you can use the optional integer argument to tell `break` the number of structures it should break out of (e.g., in this case, `break 2` would break out of the outer loop).